# Where does the absolute value come from in this integral evaluation?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have an integral which can be evaluated by trig substitution:
$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}} dx.$$

I let $x=2\sec(u)$ so that we have
$$\int\frac{2\sec(u)\tan(u)}{2\sec(u)\sqrt{4\sec^2(u)-4}} du=\int\frac{\tan(u)}{2\tan(u)} du=\frac{1}{2}u+C=\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C.$$

The solution provided, however, asserts that the answer is
$$\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{|x|}{2}\right)+C.$$
So, where is the error in my process? Furthermore, where does this absolute value come from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So, $\sqrt{\sec^2(u)-1}\neq \tan(u)$

Comment: How could I have missed this! Thanks for pointing it out. You can submit this as an answer if you'd like. I'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$. So, $\sqrt{\sec^2(u)-1}\neq\tan(u)$.

Comment: You may have swapped the equality for non-equality in the first equation

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, fixed.